# Are these definitions of complete measure equivalent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In my real analysis course and other places, I learned that a complete measure $\mu$ is one whose underlying sigma algebra $M$ has the property:  if $A \in M$ has measure zero, then every subset of $A$ is in $M$.

I was just looking at a book on stochastic differential equations that defines a probability space with probability measure $\mu$ to be complete if the underlying sigma algebra contains all sets with $\mu$-outer measure zero.  This condition appears to be stronger to me.  Is it, in fact, equivalent to the first definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent.  If $B$ is a subset of a measure zero set, then clearly $B$ has outer measure zero.  Conversely, if $B$ has outer measure $0$, that means that for each $n$, there is a measurable set $A_n$ containing $B$ such that $\mu(A_n)\leq 1/n$.  Define $A=\bigcap_n A_n$; then $A$ contains $B$, is measurable, and has measure $0$ since $\mu(A)\leq\mu(A_n)$ for all $n$.  So $B$ is a subset of a set of measure zero.